# GDB - how do i automatically run commands and save output

Tags: gdb, stack-trace

i'm new to GDB so hope it's a fair question...
i would like to run a script with GDB that get a coredump file and save the BT of all threads into a file.
my problem is to operate the GDB.
i tried:

```
GDB <exe> <core file> --command = my_script
```

where my script is:

```
thread apply all bt
```

that doesn't work of course.

is there another way to operate GDB with a certain command?
thanks alot

Nurit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do not put spaces around the `=`.

```
gdb <exe> <core> --command=my_script
```

Alternatively, just do this:

```
gdb -ex 'thread apply all bt' <exe> <core>
```